# Deploying Coldfusion EAR on JBoss 7 with Spring modules fails

Tags: spring, jboss, coldfusion

Following the instructions found here:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/168093 I modified the JAR names to match the version we are using.

When the deployment of the cfusion.ear happens it fails with this in the error log.

```
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => 
     {\"jboss.deployment.subunit."cfusion.ear"."cfusion.war".INSTALL\" => 
    \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."cfusion.ear"."cfusion.war".INSTALL: 
    WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "cfusion.war" of deployment "cfusion.ear"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer 
       (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @42f30e0a 
       (finder: local module finder @24273305 
       (roots: C:\java_dev\jboss7\modules,C:\java_dev\jboss7\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.3.CP,C:\java_dev\jboss7\modules\system\layers\base
       ))): javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer\"},
    \"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => 
                [\"jboss.deployment.unit."cfusion.ear".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit."cfusion.ear"."cfusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]\"]
}"
```

If the jboss-deployment-structure.xml is removed, the deployment works but obviously Spring is not available. Is there another configuration file that needs modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to RedHat support!

The solution was to add this line to the dependencies in the MODULES.XML file

```
    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
```